# Polymer 1.x: Accessing 'selected' items from iron list

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

How do I access the elements, properties and otherwise iterate over the `selected` items of an `iron-list`?

[Here is the JSBin](http://jsbin.com/duwasisoyo/1/edit?html,output).

1. Open the console.
2. Select two or three items from the list.
3. Click the button labeled "Show items in console."
4. Notice the problem with the output in the last three lines of the console output. They show undefined array lengths and the arrays where any object keys should be are empty.

So, how do we access the values of these selected items?

http://jsbin.com/duwasisoyo/1/edit?html,output

```
_showItems: function(){
  console.log(this.selectedList);            // Okay
  console.log(this.selectedList[0]);         // Okay
  console.log(this.selectedList[0]['name']); // Okay
  console.log(this.selectedLength);          // Undefined
  console.log(this.selectedKeys);            // Empty array
  console.log(this.selectedNames);           // Empty array
}
```

*Note: [This question uses the source code of the `iron-list` "selected items" demo](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list#selectedItems).*

Comment: The iron-list element demo does this. Just check out the source.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: This question uses the source code of the iron list demo you describe. Please give the question a closer look. The demo binds directly to the data source of the selected items. In this question, I want to access and iterate (i.e., manipulate) the data source to modify it. There does not appear to be a way to do this.

Comment: `selectedLength`, `selectedKeys` and `selectedNames` are not in the [documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list#selectedItems)... what do you want to obtain precisely?

Comment: @squaleLis: See my above comment.

Comment: I also think to remember that `selectedItems` can only be read and updates are ignored and that you need to use the methods to update selected items. Not sure, it's a while I used it.

Comment: @squaleLis: I want to access either the elements of the array of selected items (or if the selected items are an object, then I want to access their properties ... it's not clear how the selected items are stored ... i.e., in an array or in an object) so I can iterate over the data stored in said elements and/or properties.

Comment: @squaleLis: To be clear, `selectedList`, `selectedLength`, `selectedKeys` and `selectedNames` are custom computed properties I added to the demo code to illustrate this question by helping me iterate over the `selectedItems` array/object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rob from the Polymer Slack Site says:

> here's a fixed version https://jsbin.com/hiruducole/1/edit?html,output
>
> you need to observer (selectedItems.*)
>
> then you can use the change record to figure out what changed
>
> https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-observation
>
> you could also observe (selectedItems.splices) but I'm lazy and just do (selectedItems.*) which will catch any changes.
>
> Here's an explanation on change records and whatnot: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#deep-observation

Key Changes: https://jsbin.com/hiruducole/1/edit?html,output

```
/** / Before
selectedLength: {
  computed: '_computeSelectedLength(selectedItems)'
},
/**/
// After
selectedLength: {
  computed: '_computeSelectedLength(selectedItems.*)'
},
...
/** / Before
_computeSelectedLength: function(ar) {
  return ar.length;
},
/**/
// After
_computeSelectedLength: function(record) {
  return record.base.length;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the iron-list not notify the change on selectedList. You can change your method to

```
    _showItems: function(){
      console.log(this.selectedList);
      console.log(this.selectedList[0]);
      console.log(this.selectedList[0]['name']); 
      console.log(this._computeSelectedItemsLength(this.selectedList)); 
      console.log(this._computeSelectedKeys(this.selectedList));
      console.log(this._computeSelectedNames(this.selectedList));
    }
```

In addition, you should change also:

```
    _computeSelectedNames: function(ob) {
      var out = [];
      for(x in ob){
        out.push(ob[x]['name']);
      }
      return out;
    },
```

Ah, add controls to check that `selectedList` is not empty ;)

Answer (score 0):

@jeanpokou from the Polymer Slack Site says:

> maybe you need to use `<array-selector id="selector" items="{{employees}}" selected="{{selected}}" multi toggle></array-selector>`
>   like suggested here https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#array-selector